# How can I click on a specific email at Gmail using Selenium IDE?

Tags: css, selenium, gmail

I am trying to run a test on selenium IDE to enter to my Gmail, select the specific new email from all my email enter and click on a specific link that the email has.

I've been going round and round this and cannot find and answer!

I have read another post that has this help:

//div[@class = 'y6']/span[contains(., 'subject here')]

This does not help because the same email has been sent lots of times.

This case has the following particularities:
1. Since is a case that it will be run several times, emails with the same sender, subject and body will be send.

1. There should only be one new email every time the test is fun, since the idea is to enter and check the last email.
2. Inside the email there is a button that needed to be press, which I have the id, but I just need to enter the email to do so.
3. I have used the following CSS that so far has found what i need to click, but when I ask Selenium IDE to click it, it does nothing (clickAt, clickAndWait, clickAtAndWait... nothing!)

css=div[class=yW] > span.zF:[email='myemail@myemail.com']

1. I have also notice that the class="zA zE" in Gmail indicates that the email has not yet been read.

Help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strange, because `clickAt | css=div.yW > span.zF[email='myemail@myemail.com']` works fine for me. More than that, `clickAt | css=span[email='myemail@myemail.com']` will always open first message(last one) with this email in the list.

Comment: Thanks Aleh D. I used clickAt | css=span[email='myemail@myemail.com'] and worked!! :D

Answer (score 0):

BarbSchael,
A similar solution can be drawn by using `Xpath` of the `FROM` field.

I used this command:

```
clickAt | //table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div[@class='yW'] |
```

Click at the `FROM` field of `first/recent/top` most mail to go to mail detail page. // note: `tr` for first mail, `tr[2]` for second and so on.